# how to debug why an activity is not rendering the associated layout file

Tags: android, kotlin

I've been struggling for hours and ensure all measures are taken, it's launching an activity but showing a white screen, println on activity's onCreate show's no output either . Here's my checklist, please review.

**1. AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <activity android:name="ActivityB" />
```

**2. ActivityA**

```
    println("this text is printed in the logs") // work
    val intent = Intent(this, ActivityB::class.java).apply {
        putExtras(Bundle().apply {
            putSerializable("data", data)
        })
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2) // activity launches but white screen
```

**3. ActivityB**

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b) // not showing, white screen only

        println("Hello World") // no effect
    }
```

**4. res/layout/activity_b.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding background color to either your textview or your layout ?  Or changing the textColor of your textview ?

Comment: textview is not showing, println is not in the logs either

Comment: can u show the activityA whole file? Maybe `startActivityForResult` never been called

Comment: I've print statement in activityA that works, see edit please, edited question, the problem is layout is not showing.